# How to change only one tooltip?

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

I am populating a FlowLayout with Pictureboxes. As I populate i give each of them a tooltip. I have a seperate function to change the pictures how can I change the tooltip as well?

```
dim laytt as tooltip = new tooltip

For i = 1 To count
        Dim newPic As PictureBox = New PictureBox()
        newPic.Image = p.Image
        newPic.Size = p.Size
        newPic.SizeMode = p.SizeMode

        laytt.SetToolTip(newPic, ttstring)

        AddHandler newPic.Click, AddressOf LayoutComponent_Clicked

        sys.Add(a_component)

        LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.Add(newPic)
Next
```

later i have a function to change the pics in it I want to be able to change the tool tip

```
Private Sub LayoutComponent_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim i As Integer = LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.IndexOf(sender)

    If deleteModeOn Then
        sys.components.RemoveAt(i)
        LayoutFlowLayout.Controls.RemoveAt(i)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get index in sys from layout?


    If (sys.components.Item(i).GetType() = GetType(Transpositor)) Then
        Form2.ShowDialog(Me)
        sys.components.Item(i).divert = tempTranspositorDivert

        'here I want to do something like this
        laytt.RemoveAt(i) <--- THIS DOESN'T EXIST

    End If

End Sub
```

TL;DR  I want to remove/change only one tooltip text at a specific index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `sender` parameter is the picture box control that was clicked, you can use that variable to specify which control you want to alter.  For instance, this will remove the tool tip:

```
laytt.SetToolTip(sender, Nothing)
```

This will change it:

```
laytt.SetToolTip(sender, "new value")
```

Comment: no this actually adds a new tool tip. So at this point I would have 2 tooltips on the same sender.

weird huh?

Comment: It's not supposed to according to the MSDN, and it didn't add another one in my quick testing.